# Chrome pushmessaging apis backward compatibility

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

a year ago,  i used the following apis to enable chrome push messaging(now gcm) to send gcm messages from the server .

Those apis now seems to be completely broken

> chrome.pushMessaging.getChannelId(function(google_chrome_channel_id){})

The error reported when above function is used

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getChannelId' of undefined

chrome GCM apis are changed according to this doc
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/chrome/client .

is there any work around for these apis or should i rewrite parts of the app according to new api ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The old API was [deprecated in May 2014](http://blog.chromium.org/2014/09/moving-towards-single-cloud-messaging.html). Emphasis mine:

> Developers will start to see a deprecation message in the console if they use `chrome.pushMessaging`, and no new Chrome apps and extensions will be accepted to the Chrome Web Store if they use the deprecated API. Beginning in mid-January 2015, Chrome apps and extensions that continue to use `chrome.pushMessaging` will be delisted in the Chrome Web Store. When upgraded to use `chrome.gcm`, these apps will once again be discoverable via searching and browsing the Web Store. In early March, the `chrome.pushMessaging` API **will be removed** and all Chrome apps and extensions that continue to reference it will be automatically disabled. They can be enabled once again when upgraded to use `chrome.gcm`.

By now, the documentation for it no longer even exists.

So yes, you don't have a choice, you need to migrate to `chrome.gcm`